# Is restFB generated token is genuine?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I working with restFB for calling FaceBook Graph api to login, get posts and etc of users.

Created an app in developers account of Facebook.

Tried to call user details, with token generated here,
`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=8560751784547897&version=v2.8`

For Example: accessToken from the above url provides = `EAA....F`

I am able to get all user details, when I am hitting url in browser as follows,
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday?access_token=EAA....f`

I am getting following response in browser,

```
{
   "id": "1127949",
   "name": "youtr name",
   "email": "youmail\u0040gmail.com"
   "birthday": "10/27/1998"
}
```

I used following code to generate accesstoken dynamically,

```
        StringBuffer callbackURLbuffer = request.getRequestURL();
        int index = callbackURLbuffer.lastIndexOf("/");
        callbackURLbuffer.replace(index, callbackURLbuffer.length(), "").append("/callback");
        callbackURL = URLEncoder.encode(callbackURLbuffer.toString(), "UTF-8");

        String authURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="
                + facebookAppId
                + "&redirect_uri="
                + callbackURL
                + "&scope=user_about_me,"
                + "user_actions.books,user_actions.fitness,user_actions.music,user_actions.news,user_actions.video,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,"
                + "user_events,user_photos,user_friends,user_games_activity,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details,"
                + "user_relationships,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_tagged_places,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,ads_management,ads_read,email,"
                + "manage_notifications,manage_pages,publish_actions,read_friendlists,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_page_mailboxes,read_stream,rsvp_event";
```

In my callbackURL servlet, I am getting accessToken with `code` value, as follows,

```
        StringBuffer redirectURLbuffer = request.getRequestURL();
        int index = redirectURLbuffer.lastIndexOf("/");
        redirectURLbuffer.replace(index, redirectURLbuffer.length(), "").append("/callback");
        redirectURL = URLEncoder.encode(redirectURLbuffer.toString(), "UTF-8");

        code = request.getParameter("code");
        if(null!=code) {
            accessURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + facebookAppId + 
                    "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURL + "&client_secret=" + facebookAppSecret + "&code=" + code;
            webContent = getWebContentFromURL(accessURL);
            accessToken = getAccessTokenFromWebContent(webContent);
```

other functions used for this above code,

```
private static String getWebContentFromURL(String webnames) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(webnames);
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        //BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
        StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer();
        int byteRead;
        while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1)
            builder.append((char) byteRead);
        buffer.close();
        String text=builder.toString();
        return text;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And,

```
private static String getAccessTokenFromWebContent (String webContent) {
    String accessToken = null;
    int s = webContent.indexOf("access_token=") + ("access_token=".length());
    int e = webContent.indexOf("&");
    accessToken = webContent.substring(s, e);
    return accessToken;
}
```

Lets say this accessToken = `EAA....2`

If I call the below url with this Token, 
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday&access_token=EAA....2`

I am getting following response,

```
{
   "id": "1127949",
   "name": "youtr name",
   "email": "youmail\u0040gmail.com"
}
```

If I hit following url, with bio feild, I got error msg in json as follows,

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "(#12) bio field is deprecated for versions v2.8 and higher",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 12,
  "fbtrace_id": "ARkoFJVP/Jk"
   }
}
```

can some one say why this is happening for me.

Comment: Just use `about` instead of `bio` …

Comment: @CBroe Already used that, but no values coming

Comment: Your access token contains the `user_about_me` permission and you checked this in the access token debugger?

Comment: @Norbert, in my token debugging there is no scope with `user_about_me`

Comment: That's at least the explanation why you get no value for the `about` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here, to get about the user permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_about_me.

As per your comment, regarding debuggin your token, sounds like you didn't get the permission enabled for `user_about_me` by facebook.

You have to send Facebook for a review about your app and need to approve by Facebook, then only you can access the user details and other things.

### Follow these steps,

1. Go to - https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your_app_id/review-status/
2. Click on Start a submission button.
3. Select the check boxes,which you needs for permission. Then Click add Items button.
4. Then click on Edit Notes for each permission.
5. Here, breif about your app with this permission and upload a video of demo of your app.
6. Facebook will review it and accept/reject as per the norms.

This is what you are missing and it causes for your problem..

Comment: Yes, This is what I left and forgot to add my answer